How to add consecutive numbers of messages in jq command
I couldn't figure out how to do this, so I asked here.
[
  {
    "message" : "This is",
    "Identity" : "1"
  },
  {
    "message" : " a car",
    "Identity" : "2"
  },
  {
    "message" : "My Job",
    "Identity" : "11"
  },
  {
    "message" : "Is a ",
    "Identity" : "12"
  },
  {
    "message" : "Student",
    "Identity" : "13"
  }
]




1 and 2, 11 and 12 are made up of consecutive numbers.
I would like to group messages made up of consecutive numbers like this and add them starting from the smallest order.
[
  {
    "message" : "This is a car"
  },
  {
    "message" : "My Job Is a Student"
  }
]


I can't remember the mathematical formula, so I would appreciate if you could help me with the formula.

# cat a.json
{
    "events": [
        {
            "message": "# Time: 2024-09-11T17:42:56.069052Z\n# User@Host: test_account[test_account] @  [127.0.0.1]  Id: 1760882\n# Query_time: 1.090218  Lock_time: 0.000012 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0 Thread_id: 1760883 Errno: 0 Killed: 0 Bytes_received: 0 Bytes_sent: 0 Read_first: 0 Read_last: 0 Read_key: 0 Read_next: 0 Read_prev: 0 Read_rnd: 0 Read_rnd_next: 0 Sort_merge_passes: 0 Sort_range_count: 0 Sort_rows: 0 Sort_scan_count: 0 Created_tmp_disk_tables: 0 Created_tmp_tables: 0 Start: 2024-09-11T17:42:54.978834Z End: 2024-09-11T17:42:56.069052Z\nuse testdb;\nSET timestamp=1726076574;", 
            "eventId": "38492793916066929644073647519700311240525639687799308288"
        }, 
        {
            "message": "INSERT INTO test_table (c1, c2, c3) ",
            "eventId": "38492793916066929644073647519700311240525639687799308289"
        },
        {
            "message": "# Time: 2024-09-11T17:42:56.069052Z\n# User@Host: test_account[test_account] @  [127.0.0.1]  Id: 1760883\n# Query_time: 1.090218  Lock_time: 0.000012 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0 Thread_id: 1760883 Errno: 0 Killed: 0 Bytes_received: 0 Bytes_sent: 0 Read_first: 0 Read_last: 0 Read_key: 0 Read_next: 0 Read_prev: 0 Read_rnd: 0 Read_rnd_next: 0 Sort_merge_passes: 0 Sort_range_count: 0 Sort_rows: 0 Sort_scan_count: 0 Created_tmp_disk_tables: 0 Created_tmp_tables: 0 Start: 2024-09-11T17:42:54.978834Z End: 2024-09-11T17:42:56.069052Z\nuse testdb;\nSET timestamp=1726076574;", 
            "eventId": "38492793916066929644073647519700311240525639687799308291"
        }, 
        {
            "message": "INSERT INTO test_table (c1, c2, c3) ",
            "eventId": "38492793916066929644073647519700311240525639687799308292"
        },
        {
            "message": "# Time: 2024-09-11T17:42:56.069052Z\n# User@Host: test_account[test_account] @  [127.0.0.1]  Id: 1760884\n# Query_time: 1.090218  Lock_time: 0.000012 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0 Thread_id: 1760883 Errno: 0 Killed: 0 Bytes_received: 0 Bytes_sent: 0 Read_first: 0 Read_last: 0 Read_key: 0 Read_next: 0 Read_prev: 0 Read_rnd: 0 Read_rnd_next: 0 Sort_merge_passes: 0 Sort_range_count: 0 Sort_rows: 0 Sort_scan_count: 0 Created_tmp_disk_tables: 0 Created_tmp_tables: 0 Start: 2024-09-11T17:42:54.978834Z End: 2024-09-11T17:42:56.069052Z\nuse testdb;\nSET timestamp=1726076574;", 
            "eventId": "38492793916066929644073647519700311240525639687799308293"
        }
    ]
}

# cat b.json
{
    "events": [
        {
            "message": "# Time: 2024-09-11T16:00:09.408435Z\n# User@Host: test_account[test_account] @  [127.0.0.1]  Id: 5436754\n# Query_time: 0.612487  Lock_time: 0.000003 Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 130154 Thread_id: 5436754 Errno: 0 Killed: 0 Bytes_received: 0 Bytes_sent: 0 Read_first: 0 Read_last: 0 Read_key: 65078 Read_next: 130154 Read_prev: 0 Read_rnd: 0 Read_rnd_next: 0 Sort_merge_passes: 0 Sort_range_count: 0 Sort_rows: 0 Sort_scan_count: 0 Created_tmp_disk_tables: 0 Created_tmp_tables: 0 Start: 2024-09-11T16:00:08.795948Z End: 2024-09-11T16:00:09.408435Z\nuse testdb;\nSET timestamp=1726070408;\nselect * from test_table;",
            "eventId": "38492656394931242928022607514130903113177258647838851072"
        }, 
        {
            "message": "# Time: 2024-09-11T16:00:09.408435Z\n# User@Host: test_account[test_account] @  [127.0.0.1]  Id: 5436201\n# Query_time: 0.610625  Lock_time: 0.000003 Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 130154 Thread_id: 5436201 Errno: 0 Killed: 0 Bytes_received: 0 Bytes_sent: 0 Read_first: 0 Read_last: 0 Read_key: 65078 Read_next: 130154 Read_prev: 0 Read_rnd: 0 Read_rnd_next: 0 Sort_merge_passes: 0 Sort_range_count: 0 Sort_rows: 0 Sort_scan_count: 0 Created_tmp_disk_tables: 0 Created_tmp_tables: 0 Start: 2024-09-11T16:00:08.797810Z End: 2024-09-11T16:00:09.408435Z\nSET timestamp=1726070408;\nselect * from test_table;",
            "eventId": "38492656394931242928022607514130903113177258647838851073"
        }, 
        {
            "message": "# Time: 2024-09-11T16:00:12.461401Z\n# User@Host: test_account[test_account] @  [127.0.0.1]  Id: 5436209\n# Query_time: 0.528123  Lock_time: 0.000003 Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 130156 Thread_id: 5436209 Errno: 0 Killed: 0 Bytes_received: 0 Bytes_sent: 0 Read_first: 0 Read_last: 0 Read_key: 65079 Read_next: 130156 Read_prev: 0 Read_rnd: 0 Read_rnd_next: 0 Sort_merge_passes: 0 Sort_range_count: 0 Sort_rows: 0 Sort_scan_count: 0 Created_tmp_disk_tables: 0 Created_tmp_tables: 0 Start: 2024-09-11T16:00:11.933278Z End: 2024-09-11T16:00:12.461401Z\nSET timestamp=1726070411;\nselect * from test_table;",
            "eventId": "38492656463015418019136599965239450999572706325597061122"
        }
    ]
}


This is when I ran the script provided in the guide.
The ending digits 88, 89 and 91, 92, and 93 of the eventId of a.json are consecutive.
So I should get 2 results, but I get 3.
# cat c.sh
cat a.json | /usr/local/bin/jq -r '
.events | map(.eventId |= tonumber) | sort_by(.eventId) | reduce .[1:][] as $i (.[:1];
    if ((last.eventId + 1 != $i.eventId)) then . += [$i]
    else last.eventId = last.eventID + 1 | last.message += " " + $i.message end
)'
#) | del(.[].eventId)' 

echo "=========================================================================================="
echo "=========================================================================================="
echo "=========================================================================================="

cat b.json | /usr/local/bin/jq -r '
.events | map(.eventId |= tonumber) | sort_by(.eventId) | reduce .[1:][] as $i (.[:1];
    if ((last.eventId + 1 != $i.eventId)) then . += [$i]
    else last.eventId = last.eventID + 1 | last.message += " " + $i.message end
)'
#) | del(.[].eventId)' 


# sh c.sh
[
  {
    "message": "# Time: 2024-09-11T17:42:56.069052Z\n# User@Host: test_account[test_account] @  [127.0.0.1]  Id: 1760882\n# Query_time: 1.090218  Lock_time: 0.000012 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0 Thread_id: 1760883 Errno: 0 Killed: 0 Bytes_received: 0 Bytes_sent: 0 Read_first: 0 Read_last: 0 Read_key: 0 Read_next: 0 Read_prev: 0 Read_rnd: 0 Read_rnd_next: 0 Sort_merge_passes: 0 Sort_range_count: 0 Sort_rows: 0 Sort_scan_count: 0 Created_tmp_disk_tables: 0 Created_tmp_tables: 0 Start: 2024-09-11T17:42:54.978834Z End: 2024-09-11T17:42:56.069052Z\nuse testdb;\nSET timestamp=1726076574; INSERT INTO test_table (c1, c2, c3) ",
    "eventId": 1
  },
  {
    "message": "# Time: 2024-09-11T17:42:56.069052Z\n# User@Host: test_account[test_account] @  [127.0.0.1]  Id: 1760883\n# Query_time: 1.090218  Lock_time: 0.000012 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0 Thread_id: 1760883 Errno: 0 Killed: 0 Bytes_received: 0 Bytes_sent: 0 Read_first: 0 Read_last: 0 Read_key: 0 Read_next: 0 Read_prev: 0 Read_rnd: 0 Read_rnd_next: 0 Sort_merge_passes: 0 Sort_range_count: 0 Sort_rows: 0 Sort_scan_count: 0 Created_tmp_disk_tables: 0 Created_tmp_tables: 0 Start: 2024-09-11T17:42:54.978834Z End: 2024-09-11T17:42:56.069052Z\nuse testdb;\nSET timestamp=1726076574; INSERT INTO test_table (c1, c2, c3) ",
    "eventId": 1
  },
  {
    "message": "# Time: 2024-09-11T17:42:56.069052Z\n# User@Host: test_account[test_account] @  [127.0.0.1]  Id: 1760884\n# Query_time: 1.090218  Lock_time: 0.000012 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0 Thread_id: 1760883 Errno: 0 Killed: 0 Bytes_received: 0 Bytes_sent: 0 Read_first: 0 Read_last: 0 Read_key: 0 Read_next: 0 Read_prev: 0 Read_rnd: 0 Read_rnd_next: 0 Sort_merge_passes: 0 Sort_range_count: 0 Sort_rows: 0 Sort_scan_count: 0 Created_tmp_disk_tables: 0 Created_tmp_tables: 0 Start: 2024-09-11T17:42:54.978834Z End: 2024-09-11T17:42:56.069052Z\nuse testdb;\nSET timestamp=1726076574;",
    "eventId": 38492793916066929644073647519700311240525639687799308293
  }
]
==========================================================================================
==========================================================================================
==========================================================================================
[
  {
    "message": "# Time: 2024-09-11T16:00:09.408435Z\n# User@Host: test_account[test_account] @  [127.0.0.1]  Id: 5436754\n# Query_time: 0.612487  Lock_time: 0.000003 Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 130154 Thread_id: 5436754 Errno: 0 Killed: 0 Bytes_received: 0 Bytes_sent: 0 Read_first: 0 Read_last: 0 Read_key: 65078 Read_next: 130154 Read_prev: 0 Read_rnd: 0 Read_rnd_next: 0 Sort_merge_passes: 0 Sort_range_count: 0 Sort_rows: 0 Sort_scan_count: 0 Created_tmp_disk_tables: 0 Created_tmp_tables: 0 Start: 2024-09-11T16:00:08.795948Z End: 2024-09-11T16:00:09.408435Z\nuse testdb;\nSET timestamp=1726070408;\nselect * from test_table; # Time: 2024-09-11T16:00:09.408435Z\n# User@Host: test_account[test_account] @  [127.0.0.1]  Id: 5436201\n# Query_time: 0.610625  Lock_time: 0.000003 Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 130154 Thread_id: 5436201 Errno: 0 Killed: 0 Bytes_received: 0 Bytes_sent: 0 Read_first: 0 Read_last: 0 Read_key: 65078 Read_next: 130154 Read_prev: 0 Read_rnd: 0 Read_rnd_next: 0 Sort_merge_passes: 0 Sort_range_count: 0 Sort_rows: 0 Sort_scan_count: 0 Created_tmp_disk_tables: 0 Created_tmp_tables: 0 Start: 2024-09-11T16:00:08.797810Z End: 2024-09-11T16:00:09.408435Z\nSET timestamp=1726070408;\nselect * from test_table;",
    "eventId": 1
  },
  {
    "message": "# Time: 2024-09-11T16:00:12.461401Z\n# User@Host: test_account[test_account] @  [127.0.0.1]  Id: 5436209\n# Query_time: 0.528123  Lock_time: 0.000003 Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 130156 Thread_id: 5436209 Errno: 0 Killed: 0 Bytes_received: 0 Bytes_sent: 0 Read_first: 0 Read_last: 0 Read_key: 65079 Read_next: 130156 Read_prev: 0 Read_rnd: 0 Read_rnd_next: 0 Sort_merge_passes: 0 Sort_range_count: 0 Sort_rows: 0 Sort_scan_count: 0 Created_tmp_disk_tables: 0 Created_tmp_tables: 0 Start: 2024-09-11T16:00:11.933278Z End: 2024-09-11T16:00:12.461401Z\nSET timestamp=1726070411;\nselect * from test_table;",
    "eventId": 38492656463015418019136599965239450999572706325597061122
  }
]

Second, it has continuous eventID values, but I tried to separate them when the message starts at # Time.
a.json does not apply, but b.json produces the desired result.
For this reason, version 1.7 does not seem to be able to calculate large numbers well.
# cat c.sh
#!/bin/bash
cat a.json | /usr/local/bin/jq -r '
.events | map(.eventId |= tonumber) | sort_by(.eventId) | reduce .[1:][] as $i (.[:1];
    if ((last.eventId + 1 != $i.eventId) or (last.message | contains("Time"))) then . += [$i]
    else last.eventId = last.eventID + 1 | last.message += " " + $i.message end
)'
#) | del(.[].eventId)' 

echo "=========================================================================================="
echo "=========================================================================================="
echo "=========================================================================================="

cat b.json | /usr/local/bin/jq -r '
.events | map(.eventId |= tonumber) | sort_by(.eventId) | reduce .[1:][] as $i (.[:1];
    if ((last.eventId + 1 != $i.eventId) or (last.message | contains("Time"))) then . += [$i]
    else last.eventId = last.eventID + 1 | last.message += " " + $i.message end
)'
#) | del(.[].eventId)' 



# sh c.sh
[
  {
    "message": "# Time: 2024-09-11T17:42:56.069052Z\n# User@Host: test_account[test_account] @  [127.0.0.1]  Id: 1760882\n# Query_time: 1.090218  Lock_time: 0.000012 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0 Thread_id: 1760883 Errno: 0 Killed: 0 Bytes_received: 0 Bytes_sent: 0 Read_first: 0 Read_last: 0 Read_key: 0 Read_next: 0 Read_prev: 0 Read_rnd: 0 Read_rnd_next: 0 Sort_merge_passes: 0 Sort_range_count: 0 Sort_rows: 0 Sort_scan_count: 0 Created_tmp_disk_tables: 0 Created_tmp_tables: 0 Start: 2024-09-11T17:42:54.978834Z End: 2024-09-11T17:42:56.069052Z\nuse testdb;\nSET timestamp=1726076574;",
    "eventId": 38492793916066929644073647519700311240525639687799308288
  },
  {
    "message": "INSERT INTO test_table (c1, c2, c3)  # Time: 2024-09-11T17:42:56.069052Z\n# User@Host: test_account[test_account] @  [127.0.0.1]  Id: 1760883\n# Query_time: 1.090218  Lock_time: 0.000012 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0 Thread_id: 1760883 Errno: 0 Killed: 0 Bytes_received: 0 Bytes_sent: 0 Read_first: 0 Read_last: 0 Read_key: 0 Read_next: 0 Read_prev: 0 Read_rnd: 0 Read_rnd_next: 0 Sort_merge_passes: 0 Sort_range_count: 0 Sort_rows: 0 Sort_scan_count: 0 Created_tmp_disk_tables: 0 Created_tmp_tables: 0 Start: 2024-09-11T17:42:54.978834Z End: 2024-09-11T17:42:56.069052Z\nuse testdb;\nSET timestamp=1726076574;",
    "eventId": 1
  },
  {
    "message": "INSERT INTO test_table (c1, c2, c3)  # Time: 2024-09-11T17:42:56.069052Z\n# User@Host: test_account[test_account] @  [127.0.0.1]  Id: 1760884\n# Query_time: 1.090218  Lock_time: 0.000012 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0 Thread_id: 1760883 Errno: 0 Killed: 0 Bytes_received: 0 Bytes_sent: 0 Read_first: 0 Read_last: 0 Read_key: 0 Read_next: 0 Read_prev: 0 Read_rnd: 0 Read_rnd_next: 0 Sort_merge_passes: 0 Sort_range_count: 0 Sort_rows: 0 Sort_scan_count: 0 Created_tmp_disk_tables: 0 Created_tmp_tables: 0 Start: 2024-09-11T17:42:54.978834Z End: 2024-09-11T17:42:56.069052Z\nuse testdb;\nSET timestamp=1726076574;",
    "eventId": 1
  }
]
==========================================================================================
==========================================================================================
==========================================================================================
[
  {
    "message": "# Time: 2024-09-11T16:00:09.408435Z\n# User@Host: test_account[test_account] @  [127.0.0.1]  Id: 5436754\n# Query_time: 0.612487  Lock_time: 0.000003 Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 130154 Thread_id: 5436754 Errno: 0 Killed: 0 Bytes_received: 0 Bytes_sent: 0 Read_first: 0 Read_last: 0 Read_key: 65078 Read_next: 130154 Read_prev: 0 Read_rnd: 0 Read_rnd_next: 0 Sort_merge_passes: 0 Sort_range_count: 0 Sort_rows: 0 Sort_scan_count: 0 Created_tmp_disk_tables: 0 Created_tmp_tables: 0 Start: 2024-09-11T16:00:08.795948Z End: 2024-09-11T16:00:09.408435Z\nuse testdb;\nSET timestamp=1726070408;\nselect * from test_table;",
    "eventId": 38492656394931242928022607514130903113177258647838851072
  },
  {
    "message": "# Time: 2024-09-11T16:00:09.408435Z\n# User@Host: test_account[test_account] @  [127.0.0.1]  Id: 5436201\n# Query_time: 0.610625  Lock_time: 0.000003 Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 130154 Thread_id: 5436201 Errno: 0 Killed: 0 Bytes_received: 0 Bytes_sent: 0 Read_first: 0 Read_last: 0 Read_key: 65078 Read_next: 130154 Read_prev: 0 Read_rnd: 0 Read_rnd_next: 0 Sort_merge_passes: 0 Sort_range_count: 0 Sort_rows: 0 Sort_scan_count: 0 Created_tmp_disk_tables: 0 Created_tmp_tables: 0 Start: 2024-09-11T16:00:08.797810Z End: 2024-09-11T16:00:09.408435Z\nSET timestamp=1726070408;\nselect * from test_table;",
    "eventId": 38492656394931242928022607514130903113177258647838851073
  },
  {
    "message": "# Time: 2024-09-11T16:00:12.461401Z\n# User@Host: test_account[test_account] @  [127.0.0.1]  Id: 5436209\n# Query_time: 0.528123  Lock_time: 0.000003 Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 130156 Thread_id: 5436209 Errno: 0 Killed: 0 Bytes_received: 0 Bytes_sent: 0 Read_first: 0 Read_last: 0 Read_key: 65079 Read_next: 130156 Read_prev: 0 Read_rnd: 0 Read_rnd_next: 0 Sort_merge_passes: 0 Sort_range_count: 0 Sort_rows: 0 Sort_scan_count: 0 Created_tmp_disk_tables: 0 Created_tmp_tables: 0 Start: 2024-09-11T16:00:11.933278Z End: 2024-09-11T16:00:12.461401Z\nSET timestamp=1726070411;\nselect * from test_table;",
    "eventId": 38492656463015418019136599965239450999572706325597061122
  }
]

However, when I saw it separated, it didn't seem like it would work, so I'm continuing to test it. 
Thanks a lot for your help.
In conclusion, a consecutive number of eventIds are grouped. At this time, if the message field is # Time, a new field is created.

Convert all .Identity strings into numbers, and remove leading or trailing spaces from the .message fields (for clean spacing as in the desired output). Then iterate over the array and either append an item's message to the last message (with a re-included single space in between), or the item itself to the array, depending on the difference in their .Identity fields. Finally, remove all leftover .Identity fields.
map(.Identity |= tonumber | .message |= (ltrimstr(" ") | rtrimstr(" ")))
| reduce .[] as $i ([];
    if last.Identity != $i.Identity - 1 then . += [$i] else
      last.Identity += 1 | last.message += " " + $i.message
    end
  )
| del(.[].Identity)

[
  {
    "message": "This is a car"
  },
  {
    "message": "My Job Is a Student"
  }
]

Demo
This assumes that the input array is already sorted. If not, perform the sorting initially by starting with map(.Identity |= tonumber | .message |= (…)) | sort_by(.Identity) | reduce … instead.

I posted this to see if I could get at least some help with the formula, and thank you so much for guiding me so well. I will use it well. have a good day.

@P.Lonnie Re "Identity is too huge. For example, number is 38492793916066929644073647519700311240525639687799308288 … jq command seems can not treat those number": Integer precision got improved with jq 1.7, which until then was one of the key differences of Go-implemented gojq. Yet, depending on the actual arithmetics you perform, you could still try out how gojq would run your filters. Alternatively, switch to a string or array-based model for representing data contiguity.

I sincerely thank you for your response, even though I deleted the question I wrote out of waste of time.
I wrote additional test contents starting from a.json at the bottom of the text.
Thank you very much for your help, and we will work hard to achieve the results I want.

@P.Lonnie As mentioned, you can overcome precision issues by either performing the adjacency comparison on digit strings manually (instead of relying on a tonumber conversion with arithmetic addition), or by entirely re-modelling the contiguity indicator itself (e.g. using some (nested) array representation instead of a string).
